# Flex eskimo combobox - textinput is displayed over popup

Tags: flash, apache-flex, mobile, combobox

I´m building a unit converter (degree celsius to degree fahrenheit etc...) in flex 4.6.
I´m using the free `eskimo` components which provide me useful components and I'm using
the `combobox` component to select a unit to convert.

There is also a `textinput` to type in a startvalue to convert to the desired unit. Now there is a problem with the display of the popup that pops up when the user clicks on a `combobox`:

The text of the underlying `textinput` field is displayed over the popup of the `combobox`.
The strange thing is that the `textinput` field(border and background) is behind the popup but the label inside of it is displayed over the popup.

Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had the same problem and solved it by inserting

> skinClass="spark.skins.mobile.TextInputSkin"

into the TextInput.